# Instance limit error when requesting deep learning server on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deep-learning

I am following this tutorial to fire up a deep learning server: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/deep-learning-jupyter-aws#!

All goes well, however when I am ready to launch it get the following error:

```
 You have requested more instances (1) than your current instance limit of 0 allows for the specified instance type. Please visit http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ec2-request to request an adjustment to this limit. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InstanceLimitExceeded; Request ID: 6863e8f2-3976-4a6e-bda0-af4648bb961b)
```

I assume I have to update my current limits. However if I go to
my amazone EC2 console, I select my region and select the limit I get the create case screen.

I there I request a service limit increase for EC2 instances I dont see the primary instance type that I require (p2.xlarge).

Any thoughts on how I can adjust my current instance limit so I can fire up a deep learning server?

Comment: It means the selected region doesn't offer p2.xlarge. I see US West (Oregon) has it. Go here to check https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

Comment: @Rocherlee, sweet thanks for your suggestion!